# How to compare list input to a dictionary and add point if correct

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

I am trying to create an input-based program to ask students to input their responses to each question, then compare them to the answer key[dict]. If value is matched to input, add a point.

In my current code I have already found an issue where if I input "A,B,C" as the first responses and "A" for the rest, my result says 8,9,10 are correct although they are not.

What is my error in my for loop? I would also like some recommendations on how to improve this or to change my current logic altogether.

```
QUANTITY_TEST_QUESTIONS = 10
ANSWERKEY = {
    1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d", 5:"e", 
    6:"e", 7:"d", 8:"c", 9:"b", 10:"a"
}

def student_response():
    responseList = []
    
    for i in range(0, QUANTITY_TEST_QUESTIONS):
        student_response = input("Enter your response: ")
        # student_response = student_response.title()
        responseList.append(student_response)
    
    print(responseList)
    return responseList


def compare_response_to_answerKey(ANSWERKEY:Dict, responseList):
    points = 0

    for k, v in ANSWERKEY.items():
        if v in responseList:
            points += 1
            print(f"Correct Answers:{k}")
```

Comment: You've shown us the function definitions, but not how you are _using_ them.  Show us the main-level code that actually _calls_ these functions.

Comment: In that guidelines it said to show least code as possible, so I was not sure if I should include the main. However, this is it.

if __name__ == "__main__":

    responseList = student_response()

    compare_response_to_answerKey(ANSWERKEY, responseList)

Comment: Don't put the code in a comment.  Edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will work

```
QUANTITY_TEST_QUESTIONS = 10
ANSWERKEY = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d", 5:"e", 6:"e", 7:"d", 8:"c", 9:"b", 10:"a"}
def student_response():
    responseList=[]
    for i in range(0, QUANTITY_TEST_QUESTIONS):
        student_response = input("Enter your response: ")
        # student_response = student_response.title()
        responseList.append(student_response)

    print(responseList)
    return responseList


def compare_response_to_answerKey(ANSWERKEY, responseList):
    points = 0

    for k, v in ANSWERKEY.items():
        if v in responseList[k-1]:
            points += 1
            print(f"Correct Answers:{k}")




a = student_response()
compare_response_to_answerKey(ANSWERKEY, a)
```

Now with your input (a,b,c,a,a,a,a,a,a) work correctly.

Comment: if my answer is correct, the problem was there when you checked if the answer was correct.
It was enough to simply check that the element of the list with index k-1 had the same value as the element in the dictionary

Comment: Your comment should likely be edited into your answer, and the "if" is problematic. Are you not sure that this answer works?

Comment: I tried and yes, for me worked. Copy and paste to an online compiler and if you like it as a solution I'll be happy to helped you :)

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `if v == responseList[k-1]: points += 1`? Rather than using `in`.

Comment: Yes, use '==', same result. if you had had a list in the dictionary it would have caused some problems. I just changed your code :)

Comment: Thank you! this solved the problem immediately, I am going to study a bit more about iteration because I completely missed that. Correct me if I am wrong, but in your code, K-1 works because it is iterating over the entire list until -1 which is the last element, correct?

Comment: Exactly, because the indexs of on a list are in the range 0, n-1 (where n is the size of the list). In your case k is the number of the question and to check if it is correct you go to the list of answers and check if the same value is in the same position. For example if k == 1 it means that you have to check the first element of the answer list, since the first element of a list is in position 0 then just add -1 to go to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

In your `compare_response_to_answerKey` you only check that the answer is in the `responselist`, not that it corresponds with the correct answer for that question.

You may wish to zip the correct answers in the dictionary together with the response from the student, and count occurrences where they are the same.

```
>>> sum(1 for correct, answer in zip(ANSWERKEY.values(), student_response())
...       if answer == correct)
Enter your response: a
Enter your response: b
Enter your response: c
Enter your response: d
Enter your response: e
Enter your response: a
Enter your response: b
Enter your response: c
Enter your response: d
Enter your response: e
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
6
```

We can see the effect of zipping the two together more directly with:

```
>>> list(zip(ANSWERKEY.values(), student_response()))
Enter your response: a
Enter your response: b
Enter your response: c
Enter your response: d
Enter your response: e
Enter your response: a
Enter your response: b
Enter your response: c
Enter your response: d
Enter your response: e
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'), ('e', 'a'), ('d', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('a', 'e')]
```

Please note that aside from the `print` you have, you can write the `student_response` function much more simply with a list comprehension.

```
def student_response():
    return [input("Enter your response: ") 
            for _ in range(QUANTITY_TEST_QUESTIONS)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, I ran into some issues with zip. But I will try to work from your example! Thank you! Since I don't have 15 reputation points I cant upvote you! But I am grateful!

Comment: You can say thank you on SO by accepting the most helpful answer, and when you have enough reputation, you can upvote answers you feel are helpful.